# ReaderWriterLockSlim questions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, locking

In his answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19664437/4919475

Stephen Cleary mentioned

> ReaderWriterLockSlim is a thread-affine lock type, so it **usually**
>   cannot be used with async and await.

What did he mean by "usually"? When can `ReaderWriterLockSlim` be used?

Also, I've read here http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/02/07/introducing-the-new-readerwriterlockslim-in-orcas/ that `ReaderWriterLockSlim` has different quirks, but this article is from 2007. Did it change since then?

Comment: Meh, holding on to a RWL lock across an *await* is a pretty bad practice.  In practice almost nobody does this and if you ever goof it by accident then a runtime exception will warn you about it.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you've posted a question that only Cleary can answer, because you want to know what *he* means.

In the meantime, the obvious inference from his statement is that you can get away with using `ReaderWriterLockSlim` with `async`/`await` in any situation where you are able to guarantee the same thread that acquired the lock will also be able to release it.

For example, you could imagine code like this:

```
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _rwls = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _rwls.EnterWriteLock();
    await ...;
    _rwls.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

In the above, because the `Click` event will be raised in a thread where `await` will return to, you can acquire the lock, execute the `await`, and still get away with releasing the lock in the continuation, because you know it'll be the same thread.

In many other uses of `async`/`await`, the continuation is not guaranteed to be in the thread in which the method yielded, and so it wouldn't be allowed to release the lock having acquired it previous to the `await`. In some cases, this is explicitly intentional (i.e. `ConfigureAwait(false)`), in other cases it's just a natural outcome of the context of the `await`. Either way, those scenarios aren't compatible with `ReaderWriterLockSlim` the way the `Click` example would be.

*(I am intentionally ignoring the larger question of whether it's a good idea to acquire a lock and then hold it for the duration of a potentially long-running asynchronous operation. That is, as they say,* "a whole 'nother ball o' wax" *.)*

**Addendum:**

A "short" comment, which is too long to be an actual comment, regarding the *"larger question"* I am ignoring…

The *"larger question"* is fairly broad and highly context-dependent. It's why I didn't address it. The short version is in two parts:

1. In general, locks should be held for brief periods of time, but in general asynchronous operations are known to be potentially long in duration, so the two are mutually disagreeable. Locks are a necessary evil when doing concurrent operations, but they will always to some extent negate the benefit of doing things concurrently, because they have the effect of serializing otherwise-concurrent operations.
   The longer you hold a lock, the greater the likelihood of one or more threads getting blocked waiting for something, serializing whatever work they have. They are all waiting on the same lock, so even once the long-running lock is released, they still will all have to work in order, not concurrently. It's a bit like a traffic jam where a long queue of cars is waiting for a construction truck to finish blocking the road…even once the truck is out of the way, it will take some significant time to clear the jam.
   I would not say is *inherently* bad to hold a lock during an asynchronous operation — that is, I can imagine carefully thought-out scenarios where it would be okay — but it very often will undermine other implementation goals, and can in some cases completely undo a design meant to be heavily concurrent, especially when done without great care.
2. Semantically it's easy to make a mistake, i.e. with `await` you know the lock remains for the duration, but "fire-and-forget" is not uncommon, and would lead to the code appearing to lock while an asynchronous operation is occurring, but in reality it not (see the Stack Overflow question [What happens to a lock during an Invoke/BeginInvoke? (event dispatching)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34275816) for an example of someone who did exactly this, and didn't even realize it). One methodology for avoiding buggy code is to simply avoid patterns of coding known to potentially lead to bugs.
   Again, if one is careful enough, one can avoid the bug. But it is generally better to simply change the implementation to use a less tricky approach, and to be in the habit of doing so.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please not intentionally ignore the larger question if it's a good Idea to acquire a lock and then hold it during async? :) If you could detail that a bit more I'd appreciate that! Thanks again

Comment: @Don: please see edit. I think that's about as much as is worth mentioning for now, without more context and some specific scenario in mind.

Comment: "the Click event will be raised in a thread where await will return to"

Given that the Await will release it's current thread and re-acquire a new thread, thus changing the thread ID and no longer being aligned with the ID that locked the RWL, why would this code work?

I ask because this sort of situation is exactly why most people have stated not to use RWL in Asynchronous programming.

(Yes it's an old question, but it's what comes up when you search)

Comment: @Perringaiden _"Await will release it's current thread and re-acquire a new thread"_ -- that's only true sometimes. In other cases, the code resumes in the same thread. And, that's exactly what my answer explains, and is exactly the point of writing it. If you don't understand why sometimes the code after `await` resumes execution in the same thread the `await` executed in, then you haven't yet completed your understanding of the async/await pattern and what exactly `await` does. That explanation is outside the scope of this question, but there are lots of other answers on SO that address it

Comment: @PeterDuniho "that's only true sometimes" - Since you can't rely on getting the same thread back, you *must* write the code assuming it won't.  I understand why it sometimes returns to the same thread, either because it's instant and hasn't released the thread, or because of luck.  My point is you can't code *expecting* that, so the posted answer will fail when it *does* release the thread.  I want code that works in all situations, not just lucky ones.

Comment: @Perringaiden: _"Since you can't rely on getting the same thread back"_ -- you absolutely can rely on it, in the case where only one thread serves the synchronization context. For example, there's no scenario in Winforms or WPF where you could invoke `await` in a given GUI/dispatcher thread and have the continuation execute in a thread other than that thread. Any other synchronization context could implement similar behavior. Some contexts provide exactly that guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed over on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659387/readerwriterlockslim-and-async-await#comment75090788_19664437) that you had asked:

> Can you explain what you mean by "arbitrary code"?

I believe this note highlights an important aspect to "the larger question" which I will try--briefly, as I am also pressed for time--to address here. One of the main concerns here is that an await statement cannot guarantee the `Task` it awaits will run within the same context (particularly, in the case of thread-affine locks, on the same thread) as the calling code; this, in fact, would defeat much of the purpose of the `Task` promise.

Let's say the `Task` you await, somewhere down the line, awaits a `Task` created using `Task.Run`, is otherwise on another thread, or has yielded the current thread to await some background resource (like disk or network I/O). Under these conditions there are at least two unexpected behaviors which would be easy to accidentally come across:

1. If the code executing in the other thread attempts to obtain the same lock as the calling code that is awaiting it; the calling thread owns the lock and since the sub-task is executing on a different thread it cannot obtain the lock until the calling thread releases it, which it will not do because it is awaiting the sub-task that has not completed. If the second attempt to lock was on the same thread as the first, the lock would recognize that this thread has already acquired the lock and would allow the second lock attempt to proceed. Since they are not on the same thread this becomes a self-dependent deadlock and will either halt both the calling thread and the sub-task or will timeout, depending on the locking methods used. Most other deadlocks require using 2 or more locks in differing order across multiple code paths where each path holds a lock the other is waiting on.
2. If the calling thread is the UI thread (or some other context with a message pump which can continue processing requests while a previous request is awaiting asynchronous behavior), assuming it awaits a `Task` executing in another thread which takes long enough to process that the message pump begins processing another message (like another click to the same button, or any other "arbitrary code" which might want the same lock), that new message is executing on the same thread which owns the lock and is therefore allowed to proceed even though the previous `Task` has not completed, thus allowing arbitrary access to resources that are supposed to be synchronized.

While the former could cause your application or some component of it to lock up, the latter of these issues can yield very unexpected results and be especially tricky to troubleshoot. Similar conditions exist for all thread-affine locking mechanisms (like `Monitor` which is the underlying implementation of the `lock` keyword). Hope that helps.

If you're interested in more about parallelism patterns in C#, I might recommend the free [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) e-book (which is actually an excerpt from the otherwise excellent book "C# in a Nutshell")